# Compare Multiple IP Addresses to Multiple CIDRS in R

Tags: r, ip, cidr

I want to determine what CIDRs my IP addresses match. I have tried using `iptools` but the vectors are not the same size.

```
Example: 192.168.100.10
CIDR match: 192.168.100.0/24 or 192.168.0.0/16
```

Comment: In the future, abiding by the guidelines presented when opening a question and in the SO R FAQ (i.e. showing some code that didn't work) would avoid the folks ticking the downvote and close flag. (I have not done that but mostly b/c I'm the co-author of `iptools`)

Comment: I appreciate it! I had found your iptools which is different from the CRAN version, I however could not install properly in my work environment. I figured out a workaround and your package is working great, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until a more optimized method comes along, you can totally do this with `iptools` (with some elbow grease):

```
library(iptools)
library(purrr)

ips <- "192.168.100.10"

cidrs <- c("192.168.100.0/24", "192.168.0.0/16")

map_df(ips, ~{
  map2_dfr(.x, cidrs, ~{
    ips_in_cidrs(.x, .y) %>% 
      mutate(cidr = .y)
  })
}) 
## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##   ips            in_cidr cidr            
##   <chr>          <lgl>   <chr>           
## 1 192.168.100.10 TRUE    192.168.100.0/24
## 2 192.168.100.10 TRUE    192.168.0.0/16
```